# Android 2.3.6 + Phonegap + localStorage

Tags: android, cordova, local-storage

I'm developing a mobile app using phonegap & jQuery mobile.

I'm having reports from QA that on the Samsung Galaxy Y (android 2.3.6) - localStorage is null and therefore causing the app to crash.

As far as I can tell, localStorage should be supported from android versions 2.0+, and I have even added the following code to the DroidGap class:

```
super.appView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);        
super.appView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
super.appView.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + appView.getContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/");
super.appView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

So I'm struggling to understand why localStorage doesn't seem to be supported on this particular device. I'm told that it even runs OK on other devices with the same version of Android!

Are there any settings or other things I'm not aware of that could cause localStorage to be null??

Comment: Nope, localStorage is enabled by default in PhoneGap. What do you see in "adb logcat"?

Comment: Forgive my stupidity, I'm totally new to Android - how do I view the "abd logcat" when running it on the phone?

Comment: Ignore that - I've figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out by upgrading Phonegap (cordova) from 1.8.1 to 2.0.0 fixes the issue....

Answer (score 2):

You can run logcat from the android SDK installation folder's platform tools folder, on my machine this is: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools`

Just run `adb logcat` from the command prompt.  You will get lots of messages.

I have created a test app and ran it on a Galaxy Y that has the following code in the onDeviceReady function.  Using logcat it shows the not supported message

```
if (typeof window.localStorage == 'object')
{
    // localStorage is supported
    console.log('**HelloGap: localStorage is supported');
}
else
{
    // localStorage is not supported
    console.log('**HelloGap: localStorage is NOT supported');
}
```

You can filter the messages from logcat but I haven't been able to get that to work so I just redirected the output to a text file and searched it for `**HelloGap`

Comment: This is what we have done using jsconsole.com and it shows that it's not supported. However, according to what I've found on the net, it *should* be supported. Even stranger is that if I go to www.html5test.com on the phone's browser it shows that localStorage IS supported.....

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with 2.3.6 and localStorage also so I tested 2.3.3 and 2.2 AVD images together with Cordova 2.2.0 and it seems that localStorage is supported but should be called as window.localStorage and not without window scope but what is working on Android 4.x and in Desktop Chrome. But there is another problem that localStorage is not persistent when application is restarted, and I see equal problem in Hydratation, which offers again and again app reinstalation, so I think that is affected by same bug.